# Acces NetworkStream in a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, server

I am writing a simple tcp server and multible client project.
So i am here to ask , Can i acces a network stream in a thread?
To make it more clearer il list some steps what my code does.
1st.
If a client wants to connect i make a new thread using

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(delegate ()
{
AcceptTcpClient(server, y);//here it gets networkstream using server
});
t2.Start();
```

The server is a `TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 443);`

So i have a gui. I can see who has connected to server .
Now i would like to get that network stream so i could communicate .
I was thinking that when i double click on my datagrid view where the clients are listed it would open a form.
But i dont know how the hell could i even acces the thread ?
Should i make a list when client connects it would get somekind of id and using that id to acces thread ?

tl dr I need a network stream from a thread when i click on button in GUI.

Edit: I need a place where i can hold my network streams. Like when client connects it makes a new network stream so i could use it when clicked on GUI

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to use Threads and why do you want to use a NetworkStream? Both issues are very easy to solve, and neither are in fact related to each other.

Comment: I want to use thread because im pretty new to C# abaut 4 months now. So i have heard of asyncreous thing but that was bit complicated and i would just want to learn slowly and steadily.But how could you solve this ? My ear is big and wide

Comment: I've been working professionally with C# for over 6 years and I have yet to need to use `new Thread()`

Comment: But why  Aron? Does it take too much cpu or ram ? or is it bad compared to other ways ?

Comment: Multithreading is extremely difficult to coordinate correctly. The number of bugs in your code will go up exponentially by simply adding multithreading.

Comment: I would suggest that you try Networking separately from Multithreading.

Comment: But how can i then have multible clients ? That asynchronous way is pretty confusing . Oh and i cant see how  multy threading would cause more bugs because lets say . Client connects . server spawns a new thread .Then some kind of key exchange (somekind of string).Then client would send some information and server would do some stuff with it nofthing more .

Comment: I'm using threads all the time. And if you know what you're doing it is pretty straight forward. The problem in the question is *not one to be solved using threads*! Look into the respective `Begin...` methods instead for accepting, reading from and writing to TCP clients asynchronously. There are examples on the MSDN.

Comment: Sounds like you really just want to look at WCF running on IIS. Its pretty simple to search for a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, @Aron, but that's nonsense. If you want plain TCP communication between one server and multiple clients, it's very easy to implement it using the asynchronous methods builtin. Using WCF and especially IIS is just overkill for a simple task like this.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I never said that he shouldn't do it asynchronously, WTF does everyone think that my advice against multithreading mean I am against asynchronicity.

Comment: So i should focus on learning asynchronous ?is it better to use  asynchronous than something else ?Im meaning that how much computer resources does it use when were talking abaut 100 - 200 clients doing a simple ping every 30 sec ?

Comment: @aron I wasn't talking about you being against asynchronicity. I meant that suggesting WCF+IIS over simple TCP communication is nonsense when it is so easy and works for any kind of client.

Comment: @KarlMander 200 clients every 30 seconds is actually hardly worth try to learn any complicated techniques. Most frameworks will handle that in C# without skipping a beat.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar OMG Seriously, I swear you are trolling me. Are you planning to explain to him how to serialize a grid over TCP? Do you plan to explain how to separate different messages in the TCP stream for the 30 second update?

Comment: Well i thank you all for kind of helping me . I shall start studyng  asynchronous or if i find a way that i can store and index networkstreams il finish that project and then start learning  asynchronous.

Comment: @karlmander you're mixing up things. The built-in TCP server and client classes as well as NetworkStream have async methods built in. There's nothing to learn here. Just use the asynchronous methods. This is very different from asynchronous programming using `async`/`await`.

Comment: @aron there's good reasons for using WCF and I like it a lot, but I don't know where you're getting this thing about serializing a grid from. He asked how to write a simple TCP server that can listen to multiple clients. For that, WCF+IIS is not only overkill but also not an answer.

Comment: Well okay then. Il just try to get started on  asyncchronous thingy. il read some tutorials and look up some videos and then il see what i can do .

Comment: What if you just read the documentation for `TcpListener` and `NetworkThread`? There are already examples there for doing what you want. I'm going to write an answer now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the `TcpListener` documentation, you will notice the `BeginAcceptTcpClient` method, which does what you want - accept a `TcpClient` asynchronously. Extending the example given there, you will end up with this code:

```
private class StreamParameter
{
    public TcpClient Client;
    public NetworkStream Stream;
    public byte[] Buffer;
}

public void DoBeginAcceptTcpClient(TcpListener listener)
{
    // Start to listen for connections from a client.
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

    // Accept the connection. 
    // BeginAcceptSocket() creates the accepted socket.
    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(DoAcceptTcpClientCallback, listener);
}

// Process the client connection.
public void DoAcceptTcpClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    // Get the listener that handles the client request.
    TcpListener listener = (TcpListener) ar.AsyncState;

    // End the operation and display the received data on 
    // the console.
    TcpClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);

    // Start listening for new client right away
    DoBeginAcceptTcpClient(listener);

    // Process the connection here
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    StreamParameter param = new StreamParamater();
    param.Client = client;
    param.Stream = stream;
    param.Buffer = new byte[512];

    stream.BeginRead(param.Buffer, 0, 512, AsyncReadCallback, param);
}


public void AsyncReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    StreamParameter param = result.AsyncState as StreamParameter;

    int numBytesRead = param.Stream.EndRead(result);

    // Normal processing, sending reply, etc.
}
```

This is pretty straight forward. The `BeginXYZ` method starts the operation in background and calls the callback when something notable happened (for example a client connected in `BeginAccept` or data came in in `BeginRead`).

In the callback you call the corresponding `EndXYZ` method that ends the asynchronous process. All other handling is just normal.

This can handle an unlimited number of clients and is the minimal implementation. Of course, you need to add exception handling and the like, but you get the picture.